# ¿Por qué esta función me cambia el color de forma errónea?

Tags: javascript, html

Con este codigo html

```html
 <form action="">
        <div class="nombre">
                <i class="far fa-user"></i>
            <input type="text" placeholder=" nombre de usuario" required>
                <i class="fas fa-arrow-down"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="email inactivo">
                <i class="fas fa-envelope-square"></i>
            <input type="email" placeholder=" email" required>
                <i class="fas fa-arrow-down"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="password inactivo">
                <i class="fas fa-key"></i>
            <input type="password" placeholder=" create a password">
                <i class="fas fa-arrow-down"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="ultimo inactivo">
                <i class="far fa-heart"></i>
            <p>Thank you for your time</p>
            
        </div>
    </form>
```

Estoy haciendo una < form > y quiero que, si el usuario no escribe nada en el input o escribe menos de 6 caracteres y le da a la flecha para continuar, la pantalla se ponga en rojo.

Sin embargo, si el usario si escribe algo (y son mas de 6 caracteres) quiero que la pantalla se ponga azul.

Para esto he creado dos funciones:

```js
function validarUsuario(user){
    if (user.lenght < 6){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    
    }
}



function error(color) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

Entonces, teniendo la variable flechas que hace referencia a los 3 inputs que componen mi < form > hago esto: (ignorar las variables "padre" y "siguienteform" porque son para otra cosa en adelante)

```js
function animatedForm() {
const flechas = document.querySelectorAll(".fa-arrow-down");

flechas.forEach(flecha => {
    flecha.addEventListener("click", () => {
        const input = flecha.previousElementSibling;
        const padre = flecha.parentElement;
        const siguienteForm = padre.nextElementSibling;

        if (input.type === "text" && (validarUsuario(input) == true)){
            error("red");
        }
        else { error("blue"); }
    });
});
}
```

Sin embargo cuando le doy click se pone azul inmediatamente, independientemente que ponga algo en el input o no (o independientemente que pongas menos de 6 caracteres).
He probado a cambiar aquí y allá el primer if de diferentes maneras pero sigue ocurriendo lo mismo. Parece que el programa siempre entiende que es true.

Comment: Donde se encuentra el segundo trozo de código? Quien lo llama?

Comment: Es verdad ahora añado ese trozo, no había caído que hay puede estar el problema (aunque como el input si lo coge bien).

Comment: ¿Estas seguro que `flecha.previousElementSibling;` apunta al input text?

Comment: si agregas tu HTML seria de ayuda para aumentar la comprension del problema

Comment: @JDev Ahora que lo dices, veo el querySelectorAll apunta a los < i > y no a los input!

Comment: Javier, aparte de los errores de implementación que puedas tener, quiero señalar un error de lógica aquí: *Estoy haciendo una <form> y quiero que, si el usuario no escribe nada en el input o escribe menos de 6 caracteres **y le da a la flecha para continuar**, la pantalla se ponga en rojo.* En un diseño bien pensado no se debería permitir al usuario que le de a la flecha para continuar hasta que el dato no cumpla con las condiciones requeridas. Lo más correcto es **desactivar la flecha hasta que se pueda seguir** y ahorrar así al usuario una acción que podría ser inútil, una pérdida de tiempo.

Comment: Entiendo, estoy de acuerdo aunque lo estaba haciendo puramente para aprender porque en el tutorial que lo estaba siguiendo hacen eso. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Okay, tu codigo tiene 2 errores :

1. no es `lenght` mas bien `length`
2. y es `user.value.length`

tu codigo tendria que quedar asi :

```js
function validarUsuario(user){
    if (user.value.length < 6){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
function error(color) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
function animatedForm() {
const flechas = document.querySelectorAll(".fa-arrow-down");

flechas.forEach(flecha => {
    flecha.addEventListener("click", () => {
        const input = flecha.previousElementSibling;
        const padre = flecha.parentElement;
        const siguienteForm = padre.nextElementSibling;

        if (input.type === "text" && (validarUsuario(input) == true)){
            error("red");
        }
        else {
          error("blue");
        }
    });
});
}
animatedForm();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<form action="">
        <div class="nombre">
                <i class="far fa-user"></i>
            <input type="text" placeholder=" nombre de usuario" required>
                <i class="fas fa-arrow-down"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="email inactivo">
                <i class="fas fa-envelope-square"></i>
            <input type="email" placeholder=" email" required>
                <i class="fas fa-arrow-down"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="password inactivo">
                <i class="fas fa-key"></i>
            <input type="password" placeholder=" create a password">
                <i class="fas fa-arrow-down"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="ultimo inactivo">
                <i class="far fa-heart"></i>
            <p>Thank you for your time</p>
            
        </div>
    </form>
```

de todos modos, la logica falla en el punto que :

- podes clickear las flechas siguientes
- no controla mas el input con los datos de usuario, es decir : fondo azul

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración, ciertamente antes tenía puesto user.value, pero lo quité, pero nunca habría caído en que el error estaba en length (ya van dos veces que me confundo y me quedo atascado por la palabrita). Por cierto, me podría explicar por qué si el querySelector apunta a los < li > y no al input, igualmente funciona? Es algo que no comprendo.

Comment: @JavierCake eso es porque le estas diciendo que tome la clase `fa-arrow-down` que serian los iconos `<i>` para tomar el input podrias hacer de distintas maneras, el mas sencillo seria : agregar un ID a cada input `id="..."` y desde JS lo tomas : `document.getElementById("...")`. lo que estas haciendo en este caso es buscar las flechas y decirle que el campo que lo precede es el input, funcionan bien los dos modos aunque te recomendaria el utilizo del ID para los input. eso te permitirà controlar mejor las revisiones e ahorrarte algunas lineas de codigo

Comment: Gracias, ahora entiendo realmente que significa previousElementSibling, ahora tiene sentido. Ciertamente para el próximo caso utilizaré ID como antes y no me pondré a seguir cualquier tutorial ciegamente.

Comment: @JavierCake te aconsejo que mires [este](https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp) link en inglés, ahi tenes buenos consejos para empezar en JavaScript